# How to download a data asset from Azure registry

Tags: azure-container-registry, azureml-python-sdk

As the question in title

I can use `azure.ai.ml.MLClient` to connect with an azure registry.
In this registry, there is a data asset (container) named as `train`, and there are a few `jsonl` files saved in this container.

How can I download all files from this container to my local machine using azure python SDK?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the data i am having in my workspace.

[image]

You can use below code for downloading it.

```
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azureml.core import Workspace
import azure.ai.ml._artifacts._artifact_utilities as artifact_utils
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential,InteractiveBrowserCredential

subscription_id = "your_subscription_id"
resource_group = "resource_group_name"
workspace = "workspace_name"
ml_client = MLClient(
    InteractiveBrowserCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace
)

data_info = ml_client.data.get(name="train", version="1")
artifact_utils.download_artifact_from_aml_uri(uri = data_info.path, destination = "./mlasset/", datastore_operation=ml_client.datastores)
```

Output:

[image]

You can also list down the data in your workspace.

```
for  i  in  ml_client.data.list():
    print(f"Name:{i.name}")
    print(f"Path :{i.path}")
    print(f"version:{i.latest_version}")
```

[image]